# Kafka on Nest.JS

Tags: apache-kafka, nestjs

from the official Nest.JS docs we can see that

> We don't support streaming platforms with log based persistance, such
>   as Kafka or NATS streaming because they have been created to solve a
>   different range of issues.

However, you can see here how to create a microservice with NATS https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/nats which theorically is not supported as seen above.

I would like to use Kafka with Nest. Is it / Will it be supported?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**[Kafka message broker](https://kafka.apache.org/uses)** is an ecosystem that container whole codebase and other actor of your project.

> All microservice pattern that mentions in **Basics TCP, Redis InMemCacH, MQTT, NATS, gRPC** can abstract in Nest.js core scaffold.

If you want use **KAFKA** or **RABBITMQ** may restructure  your project and change it some applications that should separated and work together with message and message queue.